# Exception in Tkinter callback /// image = numpy.ndarray(image).astype(int) TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tkinter, keras

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\umutc\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\main.py", line 178, in <lambda>
    classify_b = Button(top, text="Görseli Sınıflandır", command=lambda: classify(file_path), padx=10, pady=10)
  File "C:\Users\umutc\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\main.py", line 166, in classify
    image = numpy.ndarray(image).astype(int)
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

```
# Classifier Function / Sınıflandırma Fonksiyonu
def classify(file_path):
    global label_packed
    image = Image.open(file_path)
    image = image.resize((32,32))
    image = numpy.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
    image = numpy.array(image)
    pred = model.predict_classes([image])[0]
    sign = classes[pred]
    print(sign)
    label.configure(foreground='#FF0000', text=sign,background='#000000',font ="Verdana 20 bold")
    label.pack(padx=10,pady=10,side=RIGHT,anchor=NE)
```

Comment: `image` is already a numpy array.  You do not need `image = numpy.array(image)`.

Comment: I'd also point out that your traceback doesn't match your code.

Comment: full code -->>
I couldn't understand why https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70922794/exception-in-tkinter-callback-traceback-most-recent-call-last is giving an error. I made the change you mentioned, but I keep getting the error. Could you please help? (I'm new to this stuff :( )

Comment: Please update your question to show your actual code and your actual traceback.  We cannot read your screen from here.

Comment: I took a screenshot --> https://www.hizliresim.com/2te6vrl

Comment: Screenshots are not a good way to do things here, because we can't cut-and-paste to try them ourselves.  In this case, you didn't mention that the error is happening on a different line.  The code above calls `predict_classes`, your image called `predict`.  Those are very different.  You need to read more about these APIs.